# Pegando todos os ficheiros com o nome começado por algo num diretório

Tags: c#

Quero pegar todos os ficheiros começados por algo, por exemplo, "javaw" num determinado diretório. Obrigado pelo tempo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo:

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\\diretorio", "javaw*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Para pesquisa recursiva, e

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\\diretorio", "javaw*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

[Veja mais sobre o `Directory.GetFiles` aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms143316(v=vs.118).aspx).